# Need help using sed to stop interpreting \n as new line in linux bash scripts

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I am new to linux and any bash scripts and have the following problem:

I have this kryptokey:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n
MIICSTCCAfCgAwIBAgIRAMsLZqD4PavC7NJz7+5ld+EwCgYIKoZIzj0EAwIwdjEL\n
MAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxEzARBgNVBAgTCkNhbGlmb3JuaWExFjAUBgNVBAcTDVNhbiBG\n
cmFuY2lzY28xGTAXBgNVBAoTEG9yZzEuZXhhbXBsZS5jb20xHzAdBgNVBAMTFnRs\n
c2NhLm9yZzEuZXhhbXBsZS5jb20wHhcNMTgxMjMxMTA1ODA5WhcNMjgxMjI4MTA1\n
ODA5WjB2MQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzETMBEGA1UECBMKQ2FsaWZvcm5pYTEWMBQGA1UE\n
BxMNU2FuIEZyYW5jaXNjbzEZMBcGA1UEChMQb3JnMS5leGFtcGxlLmNvbTEfMB0G\n
A1UEAxMWdGxzY2Eub3JnMS5leGFtcGxlLmNvbTBZMBMGByqGSM49AgEGCCqGSM49\n
AwEHA0IABEbH7l3CiqLA4N4wgfilYgyEuxDrMAqDX6BrFOfWhymNosjh5FlJDHtN\n
GPDKhjtrI6e1q0NC0l6wh9h9TrBn7N2jXzBdMA4GA1UdDwEB/wQEAwIBpjAPBgNV\n
HSUECDAGBgRVHSUAMA8GA1UdEwEB/wQFMAMBAf8wKQYDVR0OBCIEIH7OaekSLJda\n
S0yuV9PCsuasGTt/+/35aVBXTVbII2rCMAoGCCqGSM49BAMCA0cAMEQCIEd+YP/6\n
tCzG/LueYTEio8ApQSyz94ju07pmc3LZJDKBAiALu66LKhOpKhogY9XEFg4TScOt\n
el4dC6OnMMTmRsEtoA==\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n
```

saved in a file `$replacementOrg1` (is the path to that file).
Now I want to replace in a template `$file "INSERT_ORG1_CA_CERT"` with this certificate and safe it in `$org1`. But I need to keep the "\n" Character.
The result should keep the \n and write it into one line.

I already tried:

```
sed -e "s@INSERT_ORG1_CA_CERT@$(cat $replacementOrg1)@g" $file > $org1
```

but it interprets the "\n" as new line.

So the final Output should look like this, 1 String in 1 Line:

```
    "-----BEGIN   CERTIFICATE-----\nMIICSTCCAfCgAwIBAgIRAMsLZqD4PavC7NJz7+5ld+EwCgYIKoZIzj0EAwIw       djEL\nMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxEzARBgNVBAgTCkNhbGlmb3JuaWExFjAUBgNVBAcTDVNhbiBG\ncmFuY2lzY28xGTAXBgNVBAoTEG9yZzEuZXhhbXBsZS5jb20xHzAdBgNVBAMTFnRs\nc2NhLm9yZzEuZXhhbXBsZS5jb20wHhcNMTgxMjMxMTA1ODA5WhcNMjgxMjI4MTA1\nODA5WjB2MQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzETMBEGA1UECBMKQ2FsaWZvcm5pYTEWMBQGA1UE\nBxMNU2FuIEZyYW5jaXNjbzEZMBcGA1UEChMQb3JnMS5leGFtcGxlLmNvbTEfMB0G\nA1UEAxMWdGxzY2Eub3JnMS5leGFtcGxlLmNvbTBZMBMGByqGSM49AgEGCCqGSM49\nAwEHA0IABEbH7l3CiqLA4N4wgfilYgyEuxDrMAqDX6BrFOfWhymNosjh5FlJDHtN\nGPDKhjtrI6e1q0NC0l6wh9h9TrBn7N2jXzBdMA4GA1UdDwEB/wQEAwIBpjAPBgNV\nHSUECDAGBgRVHSUAMA8GA1UdEwEB/wQFMAMBAf8wKQYDVR0OBCIEIH7OaekSLJda\nS0yuV9PCsuasGTt/+/35aVBXTVbII2rCMAoGCCqGSM49BAMCA0cAMEQCIEd+YP/6\ntCzG/LueYTEio8ApQSyz94ju07pmc3LZJDKBAiALu66LKhOpKhogY9XEFg4TScOt\n
el4dC6OnMMTmRsEtoA==\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"
```

Anybody can help?
Thank you

Comment: I don't get you, `\n` IS a newline.

Comment: `sed` doesn't permit the substitution string to straddle newlines without additional escaping. `cat` inserts the contents of a file, not the contents of a variable What *exactly* do you hope for your code to accomplish, and have you searched for similar questions already? This is a fairly common task.

Comment: If the original CERT is in a file, `sed /@INSERT_ORIGINAL_CERT@/{r certfile; d;}' file` might work.

Comment: That is not a valid key. What someone has done is "half-encoding" (I don't know a better term) the newlines - they have added the literal string "\n" before every newline. What you very likely want is *either* the original key with no "\n" strings *or* a single line string where every newline has been *replaced* with "\n".

Answer (score 0):

That is not a valid key. What someone has done is "half-encoding" (I don't know a better term) the newlines - they have added the literal string "\n" before every newline. What you very likely want is *either* the original key with no "\n" strings *or* a single line string where every newline has been *replaced* with "\n".

With the original value you can use `replace` instead - it supports newlines in the replacement value:

```
$ replace foo $'foo\nbar' <<< $'x\nfoo\ny'
x
foo
bar
y
```

Your case should be simply `replace 'INSERT_ORG1_CA_CERT' "$(< $replacementOrg1)" "$file" > "$org1"`.

Answer (score 0):

The **`s`***ubstitute* command isn't very good with multi-line replacement strings.  But we can use *GNU* `sed`'s ***`r`****ead* command to work around that:

```
 echo "${replacementOrg1}" | 
 sed -e '/INSERT_ORG1_CA_CERT/{r /dev/stdin'  -e ';d}' ${file} > ${org1}
```

How it works:

1. `echo` the multi-line string, piping it to `/dev/stdin`.
2. When `sed` finds the target "`INSERT_ORG1_CA_CERT`" it `r`eads `/dev/stdin` and outputs the contents
3. then ***`d`****eletes* the search string line, (which is presumed to contain no other text).

The tricky part is the inadequately documented **`r`** command -- `sed` assumes *everything* after the `r` is part of the filename.  If we tried `'/INSERT_ORG1_CA_CERT/{r /dev/stdin;d}'` it would bomb with the error:

`unmatched '{'`

Because `sed` would think the filename was literally *"/dev/stdin;d}"*.   But the error message doesn't complain about the missing file, because `sed` *never* complains about a missing `r` filename.  Instead `sed` complains that there's no `}` closing brace, because `sed` thinks the `}` is part of the filename.

To avoid that error we stick an `' -e '` in there.

Comment: The `r` command is poorly standardized. The semicolon variant I posted in a comment works fine on MacOS.

Comment: Link to [tripleee's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53986846/need-help-using-sed-to-stop-interpreting-n-as-new-line-in-linux-bash-scripts/54000733?noredirect=1#comment94811652_53986846).

Comment: @tripleee, Thanks, that's interesting about MacOS (and presumably *BSD* `sed`).  It's very surprising, (embarrassing even...), to see that your prior code is functionally the same as this answer, even though I hadn't read that earlier comment and code until now.